# Resetting an inline CSS style

Tags: jquery, css

I've been trying to work out how to reset inline styles using jQuery:

```
<div id="foo" style="display: block; z-index: 1000; ..."></div>
```

I've found that I can use the following jQuery:

```
$('#foo').css('z-index', '');
```

...but for some reason I have to **call it twice** before it actually takes effect:

```
<div id="foo" style="display: block; ..."></div>
```

Am I being thick?

Comment: can you post your full code or make a fiddle so we can take a look?

Comment: I should say, I only have to call it twice when using Chrome console. If it's in a loaded file, it's fine, but when I try and manipulate the DOM from the console I have to call it twice. Seems weird and wondered if anyone knew why.

Comment: Just fire up Chrome Console and try and unset an inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do `$('#foo')[0].style.zIndex = null;`?

I realise that this isn't really answering the question, my only answer would be that jQuery can be strange sometimes. Especially when it comes to blanking out CSS styles. I've experienced this bug before.